# Wordpress plugin Post Creation

Tags: plugins, posts, plugin-wp-e-commerce

Does someone know any plugin available that can allow any users to create a post and publish it without even registering?? In fact, I want to use it with wp-ecommerce wordpress plugin found [here](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-e-commerce/)

Comment: Isn't this a little dangerous opening up publishing rights to ANY user including those not registered? It will be open to abuse from day 1.

Comment: Ya, u right, i'll allow only registered users to post, do you have any suggestion based on my requirements??

Comment: After 19 questions, I think it's time to point you at the [help/dont-ask] page to see what is off topic (hint: software/hosting/etc recommendations).

Answer (score 1):

For example [Quick Post Widget](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/quick-post-widget/). But you may see all plugins and choose better by link 
[Frontend Editor](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/search.php?q=frontend%20editor)

Answer (score 1):

Try this - http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/one-quick-post/